# Ubuntu 22 server ethernet is disabled after router lost internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, ethernet

Recently put a fresh installation of `Ubuntu Server 22.10`, router went down yesterday and then came back, but now the ethernet port seems to be disabled. Ethernet port does not flash its lights when plugged into specifically this device, and ethernet cable works on all other devices.

What I tried:

- Restarting `networkmanager.service`
- `ip link set down/up`
- `ip a` shows **"no-carrier"** for `enp0s31f6` and only has a mac address.
- `dhclient -r | dhclient`

This has happened in the past whenever the router would lose connection or power. The only fix I've found is to format the server and install a new installation of Ubuntu Server, to which the ethernet port would work again in the same conditions. I would like to be able to fix this issue without having to wipe all my data.

Comment: Are the router and the server two different things, or is the server acting as the router? That's not very clear. If they are not the same how would a change on the server affect the router?

Comment: By server I meant my computer with the Ubuntu server installation. The router going down seems to have changed something with that computer's ethernet port configuration.